# Regex to only keep email:password

Tags: email, notepad++, regex

I just want to keep the email and password and delete all the other information.

```
Name: Test1 Test1
Address: 11 Test Road
Country : Test1
Post Code: abc111
EmailPass : test_111@hotmail.com:password111$£*!


Name: Test2 Test2
Address: 22 Test Road
Country : Test2
Post Code: abc222
EmailPass : test_222@gmail.com:password222$£*!
```

**What I want**:

```
test_111@hotmail.com:password111$£*!
test_222@gmail.com:password222$£*!
```

Comment: Don't store passwords. Store salt and hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match email **only** after `EmailPass :`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.+?EmailPass : (\S+@\S+)`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
EmailPass :     # literally
(               # group 1
    \S+             # 1 or more non space
    @               # @
    \S+             # 1 or more non space
)               # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1, the email
\n      # a linebreak, you can use \r\n for Windows EOL
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I think, if you resort to "EmailPass" line, you don't even need to check for "@". `.+?EmailPass : (\S+)` will work too. Or even `.+?ass : (\S+)` :)

Comment: @ZygD: You're right ;)

Answer (score 1):

This only matches correct emails (emails, containing `@` and `.` and text from sides and between). It also ensures that after the `:` there is a password provided.

```
(?s).*?(\S+@\S+\.\S+:\S+)|.+
```

Replace with `\1\n`

Input example:

```
Post Code: abc111
EmailPass : test_111@hotmail.com:password222$£*!

Post Code: abc222
EmailPass : test_222@gmail.:password222$£*!

Post Code: abc111
EmailPass : test_111@hotmail.com:

Post Code: abc111
EmailPass : test_222@hotmail.com:password333$£*!
```

Result:

```
test_111@hotmail.com:password222$£*!
test_222@hotmail.com:password333$£*!
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3PQneO/1)