# Regex to only keep username:password and delete the rest in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to only keep username:password combos and delete everything else. The username must include at least `two or more characters` and the password must contain at least `two or more characters`. The combos must include `:` between the username and password.

```
fdsfsdfdsfsd*&$~f:fdsfdsfsdfd1234?1&*@#/
ddad1asda:dd
sdadad:ddd
dsadsada:dsdadadsdsadsadasdsadasdasdasdadasdsad
dd:dd
d:dsdasdasdad
ds:dsf
d:d
ygygygyjgjh:ggyigiygiygiygi
d:ddh
dsfsdfdsfsfdsfsdfsdfs
:
dsdsdsdsdd;sdsdsdsdd
dsdsdsdsdd@sdsdsdsdd
h
j
j
fsdfsdfdsfsdfdsf
sdfsdfsdfsddsfsdf
dsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdf
,
.
```

**What I want:**

```
fdsfsdfdsfsd*&$~f:fdsfdsfsdfd1234?1&*@#/
ddad1asda:dd
sdadad:ddd
dsadsada:dsdadadsdsadsadasdsadasdasdasdadasdsad
dd:dd
ds:dsf
ygygygyjgjh:ggyigiygiygiygi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to only keep email:password](https://superuser.com/questions/1633934/regex-to-only-keep-emailpassword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(^\S{2,}:\S{2,}$)|(^.*?(\n|$))
```

Replace with: `\1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qmoGn0/1/)

Comment: That is perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following Regexp which matches any 2 or more non-whitespace characters, followed by a `:`, followed by 2 or more non-whitespace characters:

```
[^\s]{2,}:[^\s]{2,}
```

You can see this in action (with test data) at [RegExr](http://regexr.com/5ov8k)

To remove non-matching lines in Notepad++:

1. Go to Menu > Search > Find... > Select "Mark" Tab.
2. Activate regular expressions
3. Check "Bookmark lines"
4. In "Find what" type `^[^\s]{2,}:[^\s]{2,}$` and press "Mark All". The first `^` and the last `$` ensure that it matches the whole line.
5. You'll see dots on the left hand side against lines which match the regular expression. Close the pop-up window to get back to the editor.
6. Go to Menu > Search > Bookmark > Remove Unmarked lines

Comment: That just matches the combos that has two or more characters in the username and password, it doesn't remove the combos that don't match.

Comment: @Frank, Since you're using Notepad++, on the *Mark* tab of the Find dialog check *Bookmark line* and click *Mark all*. Finally, Search → Bookmark → Remove unmarked lines

Comment: @Frank Updated instructions on how to do this in Notepad++

Comment: Thanks for that, that works fine, but is there no way I can do all the above using Regex without using Bookmarks and removing unmarked lines?